# Urbanairship java client v1.0.0 class cast exception

Tags: java, gwt, urbanairship.com

Updating from client 0.3.3 to 1.0.0 seems difficult. Not sure if 1.0.0 requires Java 8 or there is some other dependency which is conflicting with the existing code base. But it gives class cast exception on GWT. Surprisingly, it does not complain during compilation.

There is no code added so far but just the library is added to the class path and we have seen this error. Anybody came across this?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone came across this issue. The problem was introduced in urban airship java client v0.4.2 where they upgraded Guava library to 19. Your code either has to leverage Guava 19 else it will run into compatibility issues. Hope this helps.